# Matrix representation of rotation in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What is the matrix representation in the standard basis for a rotation by $\theta$ in the plane perpendicular to the subspace spanned by the vectors $(1, 1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, 1, 1, 0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

If we were working in $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, then I know how to do this problem as finding the vector one rotates about is easy. What does a rotation matrix look like in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

Comment: This means that $T$ acts like a $2\times 2$ rotation on this plane $P$, and like the identity on its orthogonal. So you just need an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$ for which, say, the first two vectors span $P$, and the last two span $P^\perp$.

Comment: @mnj It's also important to realize there is no "the matrix representation" since there are geometrically distinct rotations of that plane. The "nicest" one you were probably looking for was the one leaving the orthogonal complement fixed, as in julien's comment.

Comment: Like @rschwieb said, I interpreted that $T$ had to be an orthogonal transformation in the end.

Answer (score 1):

It is $(H\oplus1)(R\oplus I_2)(H\oplus1)$, where $R=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta}$ and $H$ is the (real symmetric and orthogonal) Householder matrix that has $\frac1{\sqrt{3}}(1,1,1)^T$ as its last column. (Or replace $\theta$ by $-\theta$ in the above for rotation in the opposite direction.)

Answer (score 0):

You should recognize that $e_4$ will be invariant under the transformation; the rest of the problem reduces to a 3d rotation problem that you should already know how to do.